# highchart save image using exporting java and phantomjs

Tags: json, jquery, highcharts

I was able to setup exporting module using java and phantomjs. I am also able to see the image file getting generated in temp folder but it gets deleted after some time 30 secs to be exact. After going through API definition I found something called as async which caught my eyes. I tried playing around with this option but didnt worked. Image file gets deleted evertime, I want to permanently save this file on file system. Any pointers in this directions would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open AbstractPool.java file, in line 117 you can find:

```
    Collection<File> oldFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(TempDir.outputDir.toFile(),filter, null);
    for (File file : oldFiles) {
        file.delete();
    }
```

Simply delete that lines, and should be enough. Or above that lines you can set higher `fixedRate`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pawel's answer you can also change the time limit in the `app-convert.properties` file:

```
# Keep files in the temp folder for a certain retentionTime, defined in miliseconds
retentionTime = 30000
```

That is the default. So, 30s makes sense.